# Multivariate plug-in bandwidth estimator local constant regression

Tags: r, nonparametric, nadaraya-watson

Has someone good references for multivariate plug-in bandwidth estimators in local constant regression? All I'm finding is for the univaraite case.

And is there maybe already an implementation in R? Like dpill() in the KernSmooth package?

Answer (score 0):

According to my latest research very few bandwidths are available for multivariate case, and only **Direct Plug-In** belongs to Plug in bandwidths category.
It was proposed by Chacon and Duong, reference is given below

```
Chacon JE, Duong T. Multivariate plug-in bandwidth selection with unconstrained pilot bandwidth matrices. Test 2010; 19: 375–398
```

its implementation is available in R package `ks` as

```
Direct<-Hpi(x)      #Direct Plug-in.
```

Other bandwidths which can be used for multivariate case lies in classical category like: BCV, LSCV, SCV, etc